# Cpu memory usage for one application using appium

Tags: java, android, memory, appium, cpu

i wanted to know whether we can hardware(CPU,Memory) level stats of mobile device while running the test(for only that application i am running the test ) using Appium on the device.

Answer (score 2):

What is possible with Appium on Android as of now

Phones should be connected to same machine where tests are running.

in test code you execute:

```
 adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo
 adb shell dumpsys meminfo 'your apps package name'
```

and in code just parse values needed. then  just print them in test logs and just manually looked through them.

Comment: is it can be done using java selenium java driver also as i will be running my script on aws device farm

Comment: Pls raise this comment as new question and tag it under selenium,  so you can get expert opinion.

Comment: I had raised in different thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340115/running-adb-command-using-selenium-in-java)